# Go to next section on scroll down, previous section on scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm creating a portfolio website for a filmmaker. 
What I want is below:
When users scroll down the window, the page goes to the next section, when scroll up, it goes to the previous section. They look like jumping to another page, but they should be in a single page. Examples are here: websites(http://taotajima.jp/, http://maxxhat.com/).

I can make this with click event, but I don't know how to do this with SCROLL.

What I want is NOT something like this(https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#page1).

My codes are like so:

```
<body>
  <section id="first" class="current">
      Content
  </section>

  <section id="second">
      Content
  </section>

  <section id="third">
      Content
  </section>

  <section id="fourth">
      Content
  </section>
</body>
```

Each section is full page view. The section that has "current" shows in page.
I want to remove 'current' class from current section and attach it to the next section when scroll down, previous section on scroll up. How can I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? we need code

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery like this,

Define your target div.

```
var yourDiv = $('#divID').offset();
```

Then use as follows to scroll to any defined div as above like this,

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: yourDiv.top}, "slow");
```

*Note* - *If you can, there are some jQuery plugins available which can achieve this very easily. one is jQuery ScrollTo. you can find many others by simply googling for them*